# Rename directory while building war-file with Maven

Tags: maven, war, rename

## Question

### Overall Goal

I want to build a Java WebApp (war file) where folders containing static content have a version number append to it for cachability. Renaming should happen automatically during build.

### Details

The WebApp is already structured in a way that all static content is grouped together inside folders:

- /lib -> All JavaScript libraries, eg /lib/angular-1.0.3 (source at src/main/webapp)
- /app -> My Own Code, at the moment /app/myApp (source at src/main/webapp)
- /api -> all dynamic servlets (source at src/main/java)
- index.jsp -> host page that bootstraps the WebApp

Everything starting with /api and index.jsp is dynamic and not cachable at all.

Everything starting with /lib is static and versioned, thus we can set an expires header of 'access + 12 month'. Content changes require a new version number. This is easy with libraries, as they don't change much an the version number is hardcoded.

Since my own app (built with AngularJS) is also static, I want to set its expires header to 'access + 12 month', too. To do so, I need to add the current version number from Maven to the end of the folder name, thus turning /app/myApp from the source directory to /app/myApp-1.2.3 in the target directory / final war file.

### POM File

```
<plugins>
<plugin>
 <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
 <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.3.2</version>
 <executions>
   <execution>
     <goals>
       <goal>jslint</goal>
       <goal>compress</goal>
     </goals>
   </execution>
 </executions>

 <configuration>
   <excludeResources>true</excludeResources>
   <removeIncluded>true</removeIncluded>
   <suffix>.min</suffix>
   <excludes>
     <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
     <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
     <exclude>**/lib/**/*.js</exclude>
     <exclude>**/lib/**/*.css</exclude>
   </excludes>

   <aggregations>
     <aggregation>
       <insertNewLine>true</insertNewLine>
       <output>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/app/myApp/js/all.min.js</output>
       <includes>
         <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/app/myApp/js/header.txt</include>
         <include>**/*.min.js</include>
       </includes>
     </aggregation>
   </aggregations>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.0.1</version>
 <executions>
   <execution>
     <id>prepare-war</id>
     <phase>prepare-package</phase>
     <goals>
       <goal>exploded</goal>
     </goals>
   </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
 <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
 <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
 <version>1.5.2</version>
 <executions>
   <execution>
     <phase>prepare-package</phase>
     <goals>
       <goal>replace</goal>
     </goals>
   </execution>
 </executions>
 <configuration>
   <ignoreMissingFile>false</ignoreMissingFile>
   <file>${project.build.directory}/myApp/index.jsp</file>
   <replacements>
     <replacement>
       <token>PROJECT_VERSION</token>
       <value>${project.version}</value>
     </replacement>
   </replacements>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I am looking for a way to copy all ressources to the target-directory, run yuicompressor, update the links and rename app/myApp to app/myApp-x.y.z

Compressing and updating the links already, but I can't find a way to rename my own app at build time.

Thanks

## Solution

```
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
           <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
           <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.3.2</version>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <goals>
                 <goal>jslint</goal>
                 <goal>compress</goal>
               </goals>
             </execution>
           </executions>
           <configuration>
             <excludeResources>true</excludeResources>
             <removeIncluded>true</removeIncluded>
             <suffix>.min</suffix>
             <failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning>
             <excludes>
               <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
               <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
               <exclude>**/lib/**/*.js</exclude>
               <exclude>**/lib/**/*.css</exclude>
             </excludes>
             <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/app/myApp</sourceDirectory>
             <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/app/myApp-${project.version}</outputDirectory>
             <aggregations>
               <aggregation>
                 <insertNewLine>true</insertNewLine>
                 <output>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/app/myApp-${project.version}/js/all.min.js</output>
                 <includes>
                   <include>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/app/myApp/js/header.txt</include>
                   <include>**/*.min.js</include>
                 </includes>
               </aggregation>
             </aggregations>
           </configuration>
         </plugin>

         <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.3</version>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <id>prepare-war</id>
               <phase>prepare-package</phase>
               <goals>
                 <goal>exploded</goal>
               </goals>
             </execution>
           </executions>
           <configuration>
             <useCache>true</useCache>
             <!-- this exclude the directory to rename from the default copy resources procedure -->
             <warSourceExcludes>app/myApp/**,.idea/**</warSourceExcludes>
             <!-- this will do the renaming : i.e. we specify the source directory relative to pom.xml and the target directory relative to root -->
             <webResources>
               <resource>
                 <directory>src/main/webapp/app/myApp</directory>
                 <excludes>
                   <exclude>**/*.js</exclude>
                 </excludes>
                 <targetPath>/app/myApp-${project.version}</targetPath>
               </resource>
             </webResources>
           </configuration>
         </plugin>

         <plugin>
           <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
           <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
           <version>1.5.2</version>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <phase>prepare-package</phase>
               <goals>
                 <goal>replace</goal>
               </goals>
             </execution>
           </executions>
           <configuration>
             <ignoreMissingFile>false</ignoreMissingFile>
             <file>${project.build.directory}/myApp/index.jsp</file>
             <replacements>
               <replacement>
                 <token>%PROJECT_VERSION%</token>
                 <value>${project.version}</value>
               </replacement>
             </replacements>
           </configuration>
         </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do it by configuring a [`<webResources>`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) element in your maven-war-plugin config.

Doing something like this should work

```
   <configuration>
      <!-- this exclude the directory to rename from the default copy resources procedure -->
      <warSourceExcludes>app/myApp/**</warSourceExcludes>

      <!-- this will do the renaming : 
           i.e. we specify the source directory relative to pom.xml
           and the target directory relative to root -->
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <directory>src/main/webapp/app/myApp</directory>
          <!-- override the destination directory for this resource -->
          <targetPath>app/myApp-${project.version}</targetPath>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
```

**EDIT**

I'm not used to work with yucompressor plugin but it seems that you can easily change the output directory through `<outputDirectory>` element:

```
       <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/app/myApp-${project.version}/js/all.min.js</outputDirectory>
```

If all your code is in `all.min.js` (I think that's what the yucompressor do, but I'm not sure) : then you don't need the `<webResources>` section in the war plugin, but you have to keep `<warSourceExcludes>app/myApp/**</warSourceExcludes>` to avoid duplication.

**EDIT 2**

As an answer to your comment.

Try the following:

- use yucompressor for *.css and *.js as indicated in previous EDIT
- exclude `/myapp` from usual war-plugin copy resources procedure using `<warSourceExcludes>app/myApp/**</warSourceExcludes>`
- use a `webResources` section to include all you non *.js and non *.css to myApp-${project.version}:

  ```
    <webResources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp/app/myApp</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.js</exclude>
          <exclude>**/*.css</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <!-- override the destination directory for this resource -->
        <targetPath>app/myApp-${project.version}</targetPath>
      </resource>
    </webResources>
  ```

Comment: Thanks @ben75. Your help is much appreciated. I thought about this approach, but it will only work for my js and css files. My AngularJS project also contains partials (html) and sprites (png) which are also static and would be left behind if I use yuicompressors output element.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try, but at the moment I don't understand the big difference between EDIT 1 and 2. Using webRessources like quoted above does not generate a versioned as specified with targetPath. I need to look into that first as way it is this way, otherwise there will be no difference between copying everything and copying only part of it.

Comment: "Using webRessources like quoted above does not generate a versioned as specified with targetPath" ... strange I tried on a sample project myself and it generate `app/MyApp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` at the root of the war. This directory contains all non js and non css files that were in my `/src/main/webapp/app/myApp`

Comment: I think I see one potential problem: the maven-war-plugin version ! can you update to 2.3 ? (there are important improvements with version 2.2 and 2.3)

Comment: I did not check the version, thank you! That could be one reason. I am also using the "exploded" goal, wich is required by (and copy&pasted from) the yuicompressor website. Let me check that.

Comment: I don't think exploded goal is a problem it seems it support all the parameters you use in this case.

Comment: I am getting closer. Simply changing to version 2.3, renaming now happens, but yuicompressor fails because it can't see the uncompresses sources files. Getting there...

Comment: Thanks for your help! I finally get it working. Bounty well deserved.